# ng-repeat not updating when pushing objects to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been taking a course on Angular JS on Coursera and I am having trouble with `ng-repeat` not updating my view after I push something on the array using a form. When I tried to log the contents of the array after the form has been submitted, it seems that everything is correct (the element was pushed on the array, but my view does not refresh to reflect this change.

I have been trying to figure this out for two days now, but since I still cannot figure it out and I am stuck, I'm going to post parts of my code here and I hope someone can help me fix it and understand what's going on.

```
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="DishDetailController">
              <h4>Customer Comments&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>Sort by: </small>
                <input class="input-sm" type="text" ng-model="in"></h4>
              <blockquote ng-repeat="comment in dish.comments
                | orderBy:in">
                <p>
                    {{comment.rating}} Stars
                </p>
                <p>
                   {{comment.comment}}
                </p>
                <footer>{{comment.author}}, {{comment.date | date: 'MMM. dd, yyyy'}}</footer>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
<div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="DishCommentController">
              <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-show="!commentForm.name.$error.required && !commentForm.name.$pristine
                && !commentForm.comment.$error.required && !commentForm.comment.$pristine">
                <blockquote>
                  <p>
                    {{comment.rating}} Stars
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    {{comment.comment}}
                  </p>
                  <footer>{{comment.author}},</footer>
                </blockquote>
              </ul>
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentForm"
                        ng-submit="submitComment()" novalidate>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': commentForm.name.$error.required && !commentForm.name.$pristine}">
                      <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="comment.author" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number of Stars</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=1 checked="{{chRating(1)}}" ng-model="comment.rating">1</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=2 checked="{{chRating(2)}}" ng-model="comment.rating">2</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=3 checked="{{chRating(3)}}" ng-model="comment.rating">3</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=4 checked="{{chRating(4)}}" ng-model="comment.rating">4</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=5 checked="{{chRating(5)}}" ng-model="comment.rating">5</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': commentForm.comment.$error.required && !commentForm.comment.$pristine}">
                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Comments</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" ng-model="comment.comment" name="comment" rows="12" required></textarea>
                        <span ng-show="commentForm.comment.$error.required && !commentForm.comment.$pristine" class="help-block">Your comments are required.</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                          ng-disabled="commentForm.$invalid">Submit Comment</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

And here are the parts of my javascript code that handles this form:

```
.controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        var dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains',
                      label:'Hot',
                      price:'4.99',
                      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                       comments: [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                               author:"John Lemon",
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                               author:"Paul McVites",
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:3,
                               comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                               author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                               date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                               author:"Ringo Starry",
                               date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:2,
                               comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                               author:"25 Cent",
                               date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }

                       ]
                };

        $scope.dish = dish;

    }])

    .controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        //Step 1: Create a JavaScript object to hold the comment from the form
        $scope.comment = {rating: 5, comment:"", author:"", date:""};
        $scope.submitComment = function () {

            //Step 2: This is how you record the date
            $scope.comment.date = new Date().toISOString();

            // Step 3: Push your comment into the dish's comment array
            $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.comment);

            //Step 4: reset your form to pristine
            $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();
            //Step 5: reset your JavaScript object that holds your comment
            $scope.comment = {rate: 5, comment:"", author:"", date:""};
        }
    }]);
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cant't find ng-repeat in your view!

Comment: Could you create a working snippet and as andre said, ng-repeat is not there in your html.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Already updated the code to show where I do the ng-repeat.

Comment: How are you sharing $scope.dish within controllers, as I see you have defined two different controllers which has two different scope. You will have to share your dish object (may be by using service). If you are just doing this ofr learning, you may use rootscope on dish object.

Comment: Your controllers are siblings, they don't share the same scope.

Comment: To be honest, I am not yet well versed as to how scopes work in angular, I'm not getting any error messages, and when I try to console.log() both $scope.dish.comments and $scope.comment right before I set the form back to pristine, I can see that the new object was pushed into the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your parent controller i.e. `DishDetailController` to a parent `div` i.e. in `ng-controller="DishDetailController"` so that `DishCommentController` can inherit the scope of `DishDetailController` controller.

After this, when you push stuff to the `$scope.dish.comments`, it will update the content of parent `$scope` and hence to the view.

Run the below example for example:

```js
angular.module('sa', [])
  .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

      var dish = {
        name: 'Uthapizza',
        image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        label: 'Hot',
        price: '4.99',
        description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [{
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
          }, {
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
          }, {
            rating: 3,
            comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
            author: "Michael Jaikishan",
            date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
          }, {
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
            author: "Ringo Starry",
            date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
          }, {
            rating: 2,
            comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
            author: "25 Cent",
            date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
          }

        ]
      };

      $scope.dish = dish;

    }
  ])

.controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    //Step 1: Create a JavaScript object to hold the comment from the form
    $scope.comment = {
      rating: 5,
      comment: "",
      author: "",
      date: ""
    };
    $scope.submitComment = function() {

      //Step 2: This is how you record the date
      $scope.comment.date = new Date().toISOString();

      // Step 3: Push your comment into the dish's comment array
      $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.comment);

      //Step 4: reset your form to pristine
      $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();
      //Step 5: reset your JavaScript object that holds your comment
      $scope.comment = {
        rate: 5,
        comment: "",
        author: "",
        date: ""
      };
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Moved the DishDetailController to a parent element -->
<div ng-controller="DishDetailController" ng-app="sa">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
        <h4>Customer Comments&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <small>Sort by:</small>
            <input class="input-sm" type="text" ng-model="in">
        </h4>

        <blockquote ng-repeat="comment in dish.comments | orderBy:in">
            <p>
                {{comment.rating}} Stars
            </p>

            <p>
                {{comment.comment}}
            </p>
            <footer>{{comment.author}}, {{comment.date | date: 'MMM. dd, yyyy'}}</footer>
        </blockquote>
    </div>

    <!-- Now $scope of DishCommentController will inheirt from parent -->
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="DishCommentController">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentForm" ng-submit="submitComment()" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group"
                 ng-class="{'has-error': commentForm.name.$error.required && !commentForm.name.$pristine}">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="comment.author" name="name" class="form-control" id="name"
                           placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number of Stars</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=1              ng-model="comment.rating">1</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=2 ng-model="comment.rating">2</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=3 
                               ng-model="comment.rating">3</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=4 
                               ng-model="comment.rating">4</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=5 
                               ng-model="comment.rating">5</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"
                 ng-class="{'has-error': commentForm.comment.$error.required && !commentForm.comment.$pristine}">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Comments</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" ng-model="comment.comment" name="comment" rows="12"
                          required></textarea>
                <span ng-show="commentForm.comment.$error.required && !commentForm.comment.$pristine"
                      class="help-block">Your comments are required.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="commentForm.$invalid">
                        Submit
                        Comment
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The atribute checked="{{chRating(3)}}" in radio control is not necessary at all. Everything will work just fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

$scope.dish in DishDetailController is not available inside DishCommentController.

One solution is:

Move the dish variable to a service and have methods in the service to get the dish variable and add comments to the dish variable. Use the service in DishDetailController and DishCommentController.

Dish Service

```
.service('dishService', function(){

var dish={
            name:'Uthapizza',
                  image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                  category: 'mains',
                  label:'Hot',
                  price:'4.99',
                  description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                   comments: [
                       {
                           rating:5,
                           comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                           author:"John Lemon",
                           date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                       },
                       {
                           rating:4,
                           comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                           author:"Paul McVites",
                           date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                       },
                       {
                           rating:3,
                           comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                           author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                           date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                       },
                       {
                           rating:4,
                           comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                           author:"Ringo Starry",
                           date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                       },
                       {
                           rating:2,
                           comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                           author:"25 Cent",
                           date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                       }

                   ]
            };

            this.addComment = function (comment) {
                dish.comments.push(comment);
            }

            this.getDish = function (dish) {
                return dish;
            }                                                             });
```

Controllers

```
.controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', 'dishService', function($scope, dishService) {
    $scope.dish = dishService.getDish(); 
})

.controller('DishCommentController', ['$scope', 'dishService', function($scope, dishService) {

    //Step 1: Create a JavaScript object to hold the comment from the form
    $scope.comment = {rating: 5, comment:"", author:"", date:""};
    $scope.submitComment = function () {

        //Step 2: This is how you record the date
        $scope.comment.date = new Date().toISOString();

        // Step 3: Push your comment into the dish's comment array
        dishService.addComment($scope.comment)

        //Step 4: reset your form to pristine
        $scope.commentForm.$setPristine();
        //Step 5: reset your JavaScript object that holds your comment
        $scope.comment = {rate: 5, comment:"", author:"", date:""};
    }
}]);
```

Another solution is:

Make the DishDetailController, the parent controller of the DishCommentController.

```
<div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="DishDetailController"><!--Parent div-->
<h4>Customer Comments&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <small>Sort by:</small>
    <input class="input-sm" type="text" ng-model="in"></h4>
<blockquote ng-repeat="comment in dish.comments
            | orderBy:in">
    <p>
        {{comment.rating}} Stars
    </p>

    <p>
        {{comment.comment}}
    </p>
    <footer>{{comment.author}}, {{comment.date | date: 'MMM. dd, yyyy'}}</footer>
</blockquote>
<!--Child div-->
<div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1" ng-controller="DishCommentController">
    <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-show="!commentForm.name.$error.required && !commentForm.name.$pristine
            && !commentForm.comment.$error.required && !commentForm.comment.$pristine">
        <blockquote>
            <p>
                {{comment.rating}} Stars
            </p>

            <p>
                {{comment.comment}}
            </p>
            <footer>{{comment.author}},</footer>
        </blockquote>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="commentForm"
          ng-submit="submitComment()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group"
             ng-class="{'has-error': commentForm.name.$error.required && !commentForm.name.$pristine}">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>

            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" ng-model="comment.author" name="name" class="form-control" id="name"
                       placeholder="Enter Your Name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number of Stars</label>

            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=1 checked="{{chRating(1)}}"
                                                   ng-model="comment.rating">1</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=2 checked="{{chRating(2)}}"
                                                   ng-model="comment.rating">2</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=3 checked="{{chRating(3)}}"
                                                   ng-model="comment.rating">3</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=4 checked="{{chRating(4)}}"
                                                   ng-model="comment.rating">4</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="rating" ng-value=5 checked="{{chRating(5)}}"
                                                   ng-model="comment.rating">5</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"
             ng-class="{'has-error': commentForm.comment.$error.required && !commentForm.comment.$pristine}">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Comments</label>

            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" ng-model="comment.comment" name="comment" rows="12"
                          required></textarea>
                <span ng-show="commentForm.comment.$error.required && !commentForm.comment.$pristine"
                      class="help-block">Your comments are required.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                        ng-disabled="commentForm.$invalid">Submit Comment
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```